# Uploaded file is not saving to database

Tags: laravel

I have created a form where you can upload video files, but I notice that when uploading it, video takes time to upload depending on the size of the file,so to avoid people staring at a screen for a long time waiting for their video to upload I will send them to a page that says "Your video is processing and will be available when ready".The video is indeed saving to the public app folder and also it saves to my aws3 bucket folder as I requested but I noticed that its not saving the file in the database and I don't know why it by passes the database. I am using laravel, ffmpeg to convert and compress videos and ajax. Can someone help me with this. here is my code below

```
//this the fileupload.blade.php
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">

      <div class="card-body">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('fileUploadPost') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="file" id="poster" type="file" class="form-control">

                    <input type="submit"  value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">
                </div>
            </form>    
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function validate(formData, jqForm, options) {
        var form = jqForm[0];
        if (!form.file.value) {
            alert('File not found');
            return false;
        }
    }

    (function() {



    $('form').ajaxForm({

        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {

                        window.location.href = "complete";


        },
        success: function() {

        },
        complete: function(xhr) {

        }
    });

    })();
</script>


 //this is the controller

 $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required',
        ]);




  $viddy=new Video;   
  $file = $request->file('file');   
 $fileName =uniqid().$file->getClientOriginalName();

 $request->file->move(public_path('/app'), $fileName);
            $name_file=uniqid().'video.mp4';
         $ffp=FFMpeg::fromDisk('local')
         ->open($fileName)
    ->addFilter(function ($filters) {
        $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(640, 480));
    })
    ->export()
    ->toDisk('s3')
    ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame'))
    ->save($name_file);
               $imageName = Storage::disk('s3')->url($name_file);


    $viddy->title=$imageName;
    $viddy->save();

        return response()->json(['success'=>'You have successfully upload file.']);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get a response? `'You have successfully upload file.'`

Comment: No I just look in my public folder and my aws3 bucket and I see that its saved(it uploaded). But I don't see in the database.

Comment: It looks like you change location based on the `uploadProgress` callback completion which probably happens before you get a response. Wait until you receive a response from your server then see if it saves.

Comment: Ok,Is there anything I have to change in my code?

Comment: Yes. Remove `window.location.href = "complete";` from uploadProgress or comment it out. And in your success callback check to see if you get the response you are returning from your server: `success: function(data,xhr) {console.log(data.success);}`

Comment: @adam ok thank you I will try that and give you an update

Comment: @adam I get a response it says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). I will show you a picture of what I am getting

Comment: I just edited my question.Do you see the image?

Comment: What does laravel.log show? What was the php error?

Comment: @NickSurmanidze its like the message telling me that the video file is not uploading to the public/app folder but i see the video file inside the public/app folder. I don't get it? Take a look at the image I just posted.

Comment: @JayJay123 Thats progress. Try and get an exception from the logs as suggested.

Comment: @adam that is all i'm getting

Comment: @JayJay123 find the `laravel.log` file. This should be in `storage/logs`.

Comment: @adam so when i'm in the log files I supposed to look at number 500?

Comment: @JayJay123 Clear the log file, attempt to upload again, then look at the log file. You should have a stack trace. Post some details here from the stack trace such as the exception message. Example: `[2018-11-08 15:36:42] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\app\UserController.php:106`

Comment: @adam I got it! The error was that I didn't use storage in the controller. Thank you so much for helping me find the error thank you  so much....YOU'RE AWESOME!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help.